# Typescript импорт файлов css

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack

подскажите как справится с проблемой?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

импортирую вверху файл css: import itemCard from '../../styles/ItemCard.css';

но typescript ругается такой ошибкой :  TS2307: Cannot find module '../../styles/ItemCard.css'.

Хотя в браузере все стили работают. Как исправить эту ошибку?

Comment: попробуй так: `import * as styles from './../styles/ItemCard.css'`

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41336858/how-to-import-css-modules-with-typescript-react-and-webpack

Comment: нет не помогает этот вариант

Comment: почти такой же глюк с библиотекой lodash и classname . подскажите как сделать , кто с этим сталкивался

Comment: `yarn add @types/lodash @types/classnames`

Comment: это для библиотек сработало)) но для css модулей нет

Answer (score 1):

## В JavaScript/TypeScript нет импорта CSS.

Это хак с использованием вебпака(и т.п.).
Приведённый ниже пример может не заработать в вашем конкретном случае.
(прикладывай к вопросу содержимое `package.json` хотя бы)

```
/* style.css */
.qwa {
    color: red;
}
```

```
// style.css.d.ts
export const qwa: string;
```

```
// Button.tsx
import React from 'react';
import * as css from './style.css'

export default () => (
    <div className={css.qwa}>
        -,-
    </div>
)
```

### есть ещё такая штука

- http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#wildcard-character-in-module-names

Answer (score 0):

кто столкнулся с этой проблемой . помогает создание файла с расширением .d.ts в корне проекта и с таким содержимым :

```
declare module '*.css' {
  const exports: { [exportName: string]: string };
  export = exports;
}
```

Comment: думаю, стоит принять свой ответ как решение.

Answer (score 0):

```js
// можно так
import css = require('./mycss.css');
// или так
const css = require('./mycss.css');
```